# Android Sqlite date error

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my android app I am trying to do an database in sqloite..I was able to create for VARCHAR... I did code for creating the databse for firstname, middlename and lastname.. it was working .. but when I add date ...DOB.. the app is crashing... I gave VARCHAR for names... and gave NUMERIC for date... I think this numeric may be mistake... but I tried giving integer,text but it isalo crashing . I will give the code.. pls check and if there any error ..pls hgelp

mainActivity

```
{

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String fname,mname,lname,cfname,cmname,clname,bday,bmonth,byear,ett1,ett2,ett3,ett4,ett5,ett6,ett7,ett8,ett9;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fullexplanationentry_xm);

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDBI", MODE_PRIVATE, null);


        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DATA (fname VARCHAR, mname VARCHAR,lname VARCHAR,cfname VARCHAR, cmname VARCHAR,clname VARCHAR,bday NUMERIC,bmonth NUMERIC,byear NUMERIC);");


    }

    public void save(View V)
    {
        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
        EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText3);
        EditText et4 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText4);
        EditText et5 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText5);
        EditText et6 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText6);
        EditText et7 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText7);
        EditText et8 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText8);
        EditText et9 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText9);



                      fname  = et1.getText().toString();

                      mname  = et2.getText().toString();

                      lname  = et3.getText().toString();

                      cfname = et4.getText().toString();

                      cmname = et5.getText().toString();

                      clname = et6.getText().toString();

                      bday   = et7.getText().toString();

                      bmonth = et8.getText().toString();

                      byear  = et9.getText().toString();


                      db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Data VALUES('"+fname+"', '"+mname+"','"+lname+"','"+cfname+"', '"+cmname+"','"+clname+"','"+bday+"', '"+bmonth+"','"+byear+"');");
    }

    public void saveddata(View V)
    {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from Data", null);
        int count = c.getCount();
        c.moveToFirst();




        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
        tableLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        TableRow tableRow;
        TextView textView1, textView2,textView3,textView4,textView5,textView6,textView7,textView8,textView9,textView10,textView11;
        tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());         
        textView1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView1.setText("FirstName");
        textView1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        textView1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        textView1.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        tableRow.addView(textView1);

        textView2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView2.setText("LastName");
        textView2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        textView2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        textView2.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        tableRow.addView(textView2);

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

        for(Integer j=0; j<count; j++)


        {


            tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            textView3= new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView3.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fname")));
            textView3.setClickable(true);

            ett1=textView3.getText().toString();
            //datas11=textView3.getText().toString();

            textView4 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView4.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("mname")));
            textView4.setClickable(true);
            ett2=textView4.getText().toString();
            //datas12=textView4.getText().toString();

            textView5 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView5.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lname")));
            textView5.setClickable(true);
            ett3=textView5.getText().toString();
            //datas13=textView7.getText().toString();

            textView6 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView6.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cfname")));
            textView6.setClickable(true);
            ett4=textView6.getText().toString();

            textView7 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView7.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cmname")));
            textView7.setClickable(true);
            ett5=textView7.getText().toString();

            textView8 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView8.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("clname")));
            textView8.setClickable(true);
            ett6=textView8.getText().toString();

            textView9 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView9.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("bday")));
            textView9.setClickable(true);
            ett7=textView9.getText().toString();

            textView10 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView10.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("bmonth")));
            textView10.setClickable(true);
            ett8=textView10.getText().toString();

            textView11 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView11.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("byear")));
            textView11.setClickable(true);
            ett9=textView11.getText().toString();

            textView3.setPadding(10, 10, 10,10);
            textView5.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            tableRow.addView(textView3);
            tableRow.addView(textView5);
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
            c.moveToNext();

            final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add(textView3.getText().toString());
            list.add(textView4.getText().toString());
            list.add(textView5.getText().toString());
            list.add(textView6.getText().toString());
            list.add(textView7.getText().toString());
            list.add(textView8.getText().toString());
            list.add(textView9.getText().toString());
            list.add(textView10.getText().toString());
            list.add(textView11.getText().toString());

            textView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent intent = new Intent(FullExplanationEntry.this ,SavedData.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ett1",list.get(0) + "");
                    intent.putExtra("ett2",list.get(1) + "");
                    intent.putExtra("ett3",list.get(2) + "");
                    intent.putExtra("ett4",list.get(3) + "");
                    intent.putExtra("ett5",list.get(4) + "");
                    intent.putExtra("ett6",list.get(5) + "");
                    intent.putExtra("ett7",list.get(6) + "");
                    intent.putExtra("ett8",list.get(7) + "");
                    intent.putExtra("ett9",list.get(8) + "");

                    startActivity(intent);



                }
            });
        }


        c.close();
        setContentView(tableLayout);
          db.close();
    }
```

Comment: Feel free to explain what "it is not working" means for you here.

Comment: I did code for creating the databse for firstname, middlename and lastname.. it was working .. but when I add date ...DOB.. the app is crashing... I gave VARCHAR for names... and gave NUMERIC for date... I think this numeric may be mistake... but I tried giving integer,text but it isalo crashing

Comment: For crashes, please include exception stacktrace in the question. If you added new columns, the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` won't do anything since the table already exists.

Comment: so how i need to give data..

Comment: Thanks Lalto ... when I once uninstall and reinstalled.. app is working correctly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` will not recreate your table because it already exists. The columns you've added after the table was created won't be there and you'll get SQL syntax errors because of invalid column names.

Based on the comments, uninstallation solved the problem for you. That's because it removed the old database and a new one was then created with all the columns.

For future needs, consider using `SQLiteOpenHelper`'s built-in schema versioning system: `onCreate()` to create a fresh database and `onUpgrade()` to migrate up from older database schema versions.

Answer (score 1):

A date in SQLite is a **string**.
Pass it in ISO format ('yyyy-MM-dd').
You can also add time ('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')